# Negative decimals question?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Can anyone show me how to multiply $-.05$ times $-.04$ by hand please?

I do it by hand and I get $.20$ but my book says the correct result is $.002$.

Comment: $5/100$ times $4/100$ is $20/10000=2/1000$

Comment: what would be answer if you multiply .05 and .04?

Comment: $(-.05)(-.04)={-5\over 100}\cdot{-4\over100}={20\over 10000}=-.002$.

Comment: If we leave out the decimals points and signs, we are left with $5 \times 4 = 20.$ Now we fix the signs: $- \times - = +.$ Good. Next we fix the decimal point: $2 + 2 = 4$ decimal points. So fit $20$ in 4 digits, that's $20 = 0020.$ Now count 4 digits from the right and put the decimal point. That's $0.0020.$

Comment: @David: $+.002$

Comment: Example $1.2 \times -0.5.$ First, $12 \times 5 = 60.$ The decimal places: $1$ (from $1.2$) $+ 1$ (from $0.5$) $= 2.$ So *put the decimal point after 2 digits from the right.* That's $0.60.$ Next fix the signs: $+ \times - = -.$ So the result is $-0.60.$

Comment: Anyone else find it sad people don't know how to multiply decimals without a calculator?

Answer (score 3):

Since $.05$ has $2$ places to the right of the decimal and $.04$ has $2$ places to the right of the decimal, the answer needs $2+2=4$ places to the right, like so:
$$
\begin{array}{r}
.05\\
\times.04\\
\hline
.0020
\end{array}
$$

Comment: Oh I See now thank you.

Comment: Maybe it'd look better if you write 5,4 and 20 in red or something. Just saying. It looks fine as it is anyway.

Comment: Why tinker with perfection?